# PHP send HTML content with PDF of Word file

Tags: php, email

I need to send HTML content with PDF or DOCX file attachment. I sent only HTML content, it works perfect:

```
$to = 'test@yandex.ru';
$subject = 'Test';
$from = 'test@icloud.com';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
?>

<?php ob_start(); ?>
<h1>Hello</h1>

<?php
$message = ob_get_clean();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
```

But I can't send file with HTML content. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "can't" means what exactly? I don't see any attempt to try and add an attachment to the email. Have you researched this? It's unclear what your specific problem is, other than it looks like you just haven't started the task yet.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use PHPMailer script,

Download link for the PHPMailer script: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->SetFrom('you@example.com', 'Your Name'); //Name is optional
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

Just change the NameOfFile.pdf to your file.html

that should work perfectly.